# Getting indirect routes Django ORM

Tags: django, orm

I am making a backend for a bus routing app and I am stuck and this particular part. Firstly this is my models.py file.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from colorfield.fields import ColorField
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class BusStop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    lat = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True)
    long = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True)
    isDisabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stop_info = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class BusRoute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    start_stop = models.ForeignKey(BusStop, related_name="routes_start")
    end_stop = models.ForeignKey(BusStop, related_name="routes_end")
    path = models.ManyToManyField(BusStop, through="BusRoutePath")

    def route_path(self):
        return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.path.all()])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class BusRoutePath(models.Model):
    """
    Path of the route with ordering of bus stops.
    """
    route = models.ForeignKey(BusRoute)
    stop = models.ForeignKey(BusStop)
    order = models.IntegerField("Bus stop order")  # This should start with 0
    duration = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
    fare_bt_stops = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s-%s-%d" % (self.route.name, self.stop.name, self.order)


class Bus(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Bus'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Buses'

    color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    bus_info = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.number


class Ride(models.Model):
    route = models.ForeignKey(BusRoute)
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus)
    departure = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    schedule_info = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="On Time",
                              choices=[('On Time', 'On Time'),
                                       ('Delayed', 'Delayed'),
                                       ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled')])
```

I have written this query to find a list of routes which will go between two locations.

```
queryset = queryset.filter(path__in=[origin_stop]).filter(
                    path__in=[destination_stop])
```

and then I am checking if the routes are valid or not based on the order of the stop as the route is only valid if the origin stop's order number comes before that of the destination stop.

```
def check_if_valid_route(route, origin_stop, destination_stop):
    releated_stops = BusRoutePath.objects.filter(route=route).select_related()
    related_origin = releated_stops.get(stop=origin_stop)
    related_destination = releated_stops.get(stop=destination_stop)

    return related_origin.order < related_destination.order
```

So my question is can I do better than this? Right now I am only giving a list of direct routes and then verifying if it's valid or not. Can I do it with a single query?

My second question is, can I give return a list of indirect routes in case I can't find the direct ones?

This is my class in views.py to return a list of routes filtered by their origin and the destination.

```
class RouteList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = BusRoute.objects.all()
        serializer_class = BusRouteSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = BusRoute.objects.all()
        origin = self.request.query_params.get('origin', None)
        destination = self.request.query_params.get('destination', None)

        if origin is not None and destination is not None:
            try:
                origin_stop = BusStop.objects.get(name=origin)
                destination_stop = BusStop.objects.get(name=destination)

                queryset = queryset.filter(path__in=[origin_stop]).filter(
                    path__in=[destination_stop])

                temp = []

                for route in queryset:
                    if check_if_valid_route(route, origin_stop, destination_stop):
                        temp.append(route)

                queryset = temp

                if(len(queryset)) == 0:
                    raise NotFound(
                        "We were unable to find any direct routes between these stops")
            except BusStop.DoesNotExist:
                raise NotFound("The origin or destination does not exist")
        return queryset
```

Comment: This is a bit harder than you think. You'll need to use a shortest-path graph algorithm, like Dijkstra's; you certainly can't do it directly in the ORM.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have neo4j lined up in my mind if I am unable to do it with the relational table. What about the first question though ie finding direct routes based on the order. Can I design that query better?